# Save/retrieve an array of structure to iCloud

Tags: arrays, swift, structure, icloud

I'm actually learning how to save data to iCloud. I'm able to save/retrieve string/number without problem, but I have a variable of struct that I want to save/retrieve from the cloud and I can't figure out how to do that. I have tried a lot of different things with no result.

Maybe someone can give me an exemple of code that can save/retrieve this variable "Var2" from iCloud?

```
struct structure: Codable{
    var a : String!
    var b : String!
    var c : String!
    var d : String!
    var e : Double!
}

var Var2 = [
    structure(a: "-12.1", b: "5.9", c: "Hello", d: "2017-01-21 05:55:55", e: 5),
    structure(a: "151.17", b: "-1.8", c: "All", d: "2018-04-27 07:54:25", e: 0)
]
```

In case you need my actual code:

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    struct structure: Codable{
        var a : String!
        var b : String!
        var c : String!
        var d : String!
        var e : Double!}


    @IBAction func Button(_ sender: Any) {

        let Var1 = "Have Fun :)"     

        let Var2 = [
            structure(a: "-12.1", b: "5.9", c: "Hello", d: "2017-01-21 05:55:55", e: 5),
            structure(a: "151.17", b: "-1.8", c: "All", d: "2018-04-27 07:54:25", e: 0)]



        let MyRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "Test")

        // Changing the next line to "Var2" give an error
        MyRecord.setValue(Var1, forKey: "Content1")

        CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase.save(MyRecord) { (record, error) in
            guard record != nil else { return }
            print("saved record")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but 1) Name structs with a starting capital letter 2) **Never ever** declare members in structs conforming to `Codable` as implicit unwrapped optionals. Remove the exclamation marks. The code does compile

Answer (score 1):

As partially mentioned in the comments name structs with starting capital letter and variables with starting lowercase letter and declare the members as non-optional

```
struct Structure: Codable {
    var a, b, c, d : String
    var e : Double
}
```

The most efficient solution is to create a new record type with attributes corresponding to the struct members and save each `Structure` instance separately

```
for item in var2 {    

   let myRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "Structure")
   myRecord["a"] = item.a as CKRecordValue
   myRecord["b"] = item.b as CKRecordValue
   // etc.
   myRecord["e"] = NSNumber(value: item.e)
}
...
```

Alternatively declare the `Content1` attribute as `(NS)Data` and encode the struct array with `JSONEncoder`

```
 do {
    let data = JSONEncoder().encode(var2)
    let myRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "Test")
    myRecord["Content1"] = data
 } catch { print(error) }
```